# Why a monoidal category with only one object is a monoid in the category of monoids?

Tags: category-theory, monoid, monoidal-categories

I'm reading Chapter 4 in Steve Awodey's Category Theory and it mentions

> A discrete monoidal category, that is, one with a discrete underlying category, is obviously just a regular monoid (in $Sets$), while a monoidal category with only one object is a monoidal monoid, and thus exactly a commutative monoid, by the foregoing remark 4.7.

The remark says

> Note that we did not really need the full group structure in this argument. Indeed, the same result holds for monoids in the category of monoids: these are exactly the commutative monoids.

Maybe it's obvious to a category theory expert that monoidal monoid and the monoid in the category of monoids have the same meaning but I can't make the connection. My understanding is the category formed by morphisms in the monoidal monoid is indeed a monoid $(M,id, \circ)$ and because it is a monoidal category $(M,\otimes,I)$ we can define the homomorphisms $\mu = \otimes$ and $\eta = I$ to makes it a monoid in the category of monoids. Is that right?

And I was also wondering why the same does not apply to the discrete monoidal category. I am grateful for explanations.

Comment: That a monoid in the category of monoids is a commutative monoid (and the two products are the same) is the Eckmann-Hilton Argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only object in a monoidal category with one object is the unit $I$. Thus the only morphisms are those from $I$ to itself. These include the identity morphism and are closed under the associative composition, so form a monoid by definition.
Now the monoidal structure necessitates that $I\otimes I$ is the same as $I$. Consequently, given two morphisms $f,g\colon I\to I$, you can interpret $f\otimes g\colon I\otimes I\to I\otimes I$ as a morphism $I\to I$. Thus, $\otimes$ gives a second way of combining morphisms $I\to I$. Moreover, the properties of $\otimes$ require that identity morphisms are a unit for this way of combining as well, and that it distributes over the first way: $ff'\otimes gg'=(f\otimes g)(f'\otimes g')$. This is the "monoid in the category of monoids" that is meant.